# What does "while" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The scientific organization -----the newspaper for prominently covering the predictions of a psychic **while** -----to report on a major research conference.

Without getting any hint as to which subject (scientific organization / newspaper) the second verb after  **while** refer to, from the two verbs supposedly placed in the two blanks.

My thought: the scientific organization.

Comment: It makes no obvious sense to me. Looks like a C&P error or other mistake.

Comment: @Robusto, how come?

Comment: Which part doesn't make sense?

Comment: "excoriates" ... "failing"

Comment: @GregLee, how do you see which subject "failing" refers to?

Comment: You're asking about the understood subject of the second verb?  It's the newspaper.  Nothing else would make sense.  For one thing, it is newspapers that report.

Comment: *While* seems to want to be an adverb here, not a noun. None of the usual markers for interpreting it as a noun are present. And as an adverb it should be modifying some missing portion of the sentence. You're asking us to make sense of one of the most poorly constructed sentences I've seen outside of grade school. The answer must be: Who knows? Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @GregLee, but jousting looking at it grammatically, and not taking any hint from the text, how can you know?

Comment: Grammatically, the understood subject of the second verb could be the main sentence subject, "the scientific organization".

Comment: I don't know genuinely. If prediction was singular, I might suggest "while" has been mistaken for "wile" but it is plural, suggesting an acting actor making multiple predictions, rather than the prediction being an act like a trick...

Comment: Grammar doesn't help you here; you need context. Consider: *The scientific organization reprimanded the newspaper for prominently covering the predictions of a psychic while continuing to defend scientific research on ghosts and spirits.* Here, it's probably the scientific organization that is continuing to defend them.

Answer (score 5):

I am puzzled by the fact that you have omitted the two verbs. I shall put them back, or at least two plausible alternatives.

> *The scientific organization criticised the newspaper for prominently covering the predictions of a psychic while failing to report on a major research conference.*

Here **"while" is a conjunction** (or conjunctive adverb). It doesn't refer to anything. It connects the two parts of the sentence.

If you have any doubt about it being a conjunction, notice that you could replace "while" with "and" or "but" and the sentence would still make sense.